# SQL INTERSECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display table with the relevant columns. For instance, there are 3 tables (department, dept_emp and employees). If I am interested in only dept_no, my query should return department and dept_emp tables. However, if I am interested in dept_no and emp_no, the result should be only dept_emp table.

So I came up with this query, but apparently there is a syntax error. May I know if there are any other alternatives?

```
(SELECT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'dept_no')
INTERSECT
(SELECT TABLE_NAME
 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'empt_no')
```

Comment: It depends on your DB. For example MySql does not support INTERSECT. So if you specify what are you using it might help to answer

Comment: @Uriil, I see. I wasn't aware of that. And yes you are right, I am using mysql. Is there any other alternative to query to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you using MySql, you can do it via subquery:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'dept_no' AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'empt_no')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'dept_no'
INTERSECT
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'empt_no'
```

Comment: Uril is right, the query wun work because mysql doesn't support intersect.